# Trying to sort a large csv file but the output is not being written to another file

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a (very) large csv file almost around 70GB which I am trying to sort using the `sort` command. As much as I am trying, the output is not being written to file. Here is what I tried

```
sort -T /data/data/.tmp -t "," -k 38 /data/data/raw/KKR.csv > /data/data/raw/KKR_38.csv
sort -T /data/data/.tmp -t "," -k 38 /data/data/raw/KKR.csv -o /data/data/raw/KKR-38.csv
```

What happens is that the KKR_38.csv file is created and its size is the same as the KKR.csv file but there is nothing inside it. When I do

```
head -n 100 /data/data/raw/KKR_38.csv
```

It prints out 100 empty lines.

Comment: could you take the first 100 lines of your BIG `csv` file and `sort` them using the same command you are using, please let us know if you have any output, thanks!!!

Comment: Please add samples, without showing sample it is very difficult for us to help here, add them in CODE TAGS in your post please.

Comment: @Allan, yes I am able to sort just 100 lines and the output is being saved to file. I don't see 100 empty lines when I open the output file.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, what sort of samples are you looking for? Are you looking for a sample of the csv file? It is a large csv file with many columns and rows. I want to sort by column 38.

Comment: @thisisshantzz, yes please show some sample of your file(only few line) and output expected(only few lines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you sort, it is quite normal the empty lines come first.  Try this:

```
tail -100 /data/data/raw/KKR_38.csv
```

Comment: Turns out you were correct and I feel a little ashamed here. The file I was working with had almost 31 million rows and approximately 41,000 lines were empty. Thanks for helping me out here.

Comment: My pleasure (no pun intended :-) )   I didn't see it immediately myself, but as you said the output was the same size, I was thinking, what can be in there, have the original contents been replaced by blanks?  Then my euro fell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following commands if you want to not take into account the empty lines:

```
cat -s /data/data/raw/KKR_38.csv | less #to squeeze the successive empty lines to only one
```

or if you want to remove them:

```
sed '/^$/d' /data/data/raw/KKR_38.csv | less
```

You can redirect the output of those commands to create another file without the empty line (watch out for the space on your file system).